# Android Oreo - how do I set Adaptive Icons in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova

Just wondering if anyone been able to set adaptive icons on Cordova for Android Oreo? I'm using the android 6.4.0 and my square icon shrinks to fit the circle. I just want it to not shrink. I don't care if the corners are clipped off from the rounding.

Comment: @CharliePrynn does my answer help?

Comment: Thanks for your help @CharliePrynn. I'll have to test it out in the next release of our app.

Comment: I have tried doing the suggested answers but my icon is still showing inside a white box, instead of filling the who icon. My background generated inside drawable-v24 from the android studio. Any ideas?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**WARNING: Don't use this answer. This is now supported out of the box as of Cordova 9. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55169307/2947592**

I created the icons as described in https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html#create-adaptive, copied them to `res/android` and use the following configuration:

config.xml:

```
<widget ... xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="res/android/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml" target="app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml" target="app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
    </platform>    
</widget>
```

Comment: I created the assets with Android Studio, copied to res/android of root of Phonegap project, added the xml you provided to config.xml, and my icon still shows as a tiny square icon within the white-backround circle as it was before. I'm using Phonegap 7.1.1. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: @CalebPitman Try deleting the `platforms` folder, and then recreating the` cordova prepare` environment.

Comment: I had to remove `app/src/main` from the `target` for this to work.

Comment: I was using an old version of cordova-android, check this page for info https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html

Comment: I had to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the widget tag of config.xml to get this to work.

Comment: I had to change the target to start with res/

Comment: I finally got this to work, but the icon is a circle. Any idea how to make it a square? The Android Studio has several styles, and "Square" is one.

Comment: I can't find the option New > Image Asset as the tut says

Comment: If you select a background color instead of an image the first resource file will be `<resource-file src="res/android/values/ic_launcher_background.xml" target="app/src/main/res/values/ic_launcher_background.xml" />` (values instead of drawable). Thanks for posting this solution, really helped me out!

Comment: Can anyone offer clarity on "copied them to res/android"? Does this mean "copy the 'res' folder from the Android Studio project to 'resources/android/res'"? Or to the 'platform/android' folder?

Comment: I had to make the targets `res` instead of `app/src/main/res`

Comment: Why do you use <resource-file> instead of <icon> tag as shown in the cordova docs?

Comment: I had to add the ic_launcher_foreground for each icon

Comment: I am using my legacy app icon.png as my `foreground` asset image and using a `color:white` as my background.  But when Image Asset goes to generate everything it does not generate a `icon_launcher_foreground.xml` file - without this file my build fails because both `ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml` reference the foregound.xml file. It does generate all the `ic_launcher_foreground.png` images though.   If I remove the foreground.xml reference, my app builds but the icon is just the white background. I started a new project and got the same results, whats the magic I am missing here?

Answer (score 26):

**WARNING: Don't use this answer. This is now supported out of the box as of Cordova 9. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55169307/2947592**

So while the above answers helped me get to an answer, they are either dated or incomplete. So, to help anyone moving forward, this is a complete answer with all the ins and outs I could think of.

**Step 1: Create the icons**

You'll want to do this using the Image Asset Studio (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio). There a number of guides on doing this.

**Step 2: Move the icons to your ionic/cordova project**

Copy the entire `res` folder into your project. The below example is for ionic v1.

```
cp -a AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication4/app/src/main/res MyIonicProject/myapp/resources/android/adaptiveicon
```

**Step 3: Edit config.xml**

First, to use the icons (this is missing from other answers), you need to alter the top `widget` line. You'll want to add `xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to it, so it looks like the below. This allows the system to change the `AndroidMenifest.xml` file.

```
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Next, you'll need to adjust the platform section of your `config.xml`.

First remove any instances of `<icon density= ... />` from the `<platform name="android">` section.

Then, Add in the alteration to the `Android Manifest` file:

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
    <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
</edit-config>
```

And lastly, for every file in the new `resources/android/adaptiveicon` folder, you will need to add a line like this:

```
<resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/<folder>/<file>" target="app/src/main/res/<folder>/<file>" />
```

Make sure every file is represented! Your final `platform` section will probably look like this (this example is for when a PNG is used for both foreground and background):

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
    </edit-config>
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml" target="app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/drawable-v24/ic_launcher_foreground.xml" target="app/src/main/res/drawable-v24/ic_launcher_foreground.xml" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
</platform>
```

**Step 4: Play it safe, clean the Android platform**

Run the following commands to clean the platform.

```
cd myapp
rm -rf platforms/android
ionic cordova prepare
```

For good measure, fix the bugs with the Android emulator start-up in ionic:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gegenokitaro/cordova-android/8d497784ac4a40a9689e616cd486c4ed07d3e063/bin/templates/cordova/lib/emulator.js -O platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js
```

**Step 5: Build!**

Build:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

Or Emulate:

```
ionic cordova emulate android --consolelogs --serverlogs --target "Android8"
```

Comment: are you sure step 3 is still up to date? After creating and testing the icons I can not find the following anywhere in my manifest: `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"`
So i believe it also works without.

Answer (score 14):

This is now supported by Cordova Android 8.0.0. See the [announcement](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2019/02/16/cordova-android-release-8.0.0.html) and the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/images.html#android).

For example, define the icons as follows in your config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
        <resource-file src="res/icons/android/colors.xml" target="/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml" />
        <icon density="ldpi" background="@color/background" foreground="res/icons/android/ldpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" background="@color/background" foreground="res/icons/android/mdpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" background="@color/background" foreground="res/icons/android/hdpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" background="@color/background" foreground="res/icons/android/xhdpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" background="@color/background" foreground="res/icons/android/xxhdpi-foreground.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" background="@color/background" foreground="res/icons/android/xxxhdpi-foreground.png" />
    </platform>
```

With the colors.xml looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="background">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update & quick example!

Answer (score 13):

**WARNING: Don't use this answer. This is now supported out of the box as of Cordova 9. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55169307/2947592**

Recent Android uses Adaptive Icons which has background and foreground images along with some xml files. This is what I did to set-up Adaptive Icons in my ionic application:

1. In `config.xml`, I set `android-minSdkVersion` to version 26.

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="26" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
```

2. In `config.xml`, delete the `icon density` tags and remove these lines:

```
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
```

3. Next, I had to create the Android Adaptive Icons. For this I used Image Assets that comes as part of Android Studio. At first, I created 2 the background image and the transparent icon only image to use as foreground in png format from photoshop. After that, I did these steps to generate the icons:

- Open Android Studio and create a new project or open the existing project.
- Click on app -> res in the left sidebar. Right clicked on res -> New -> Image Assets

[image]

- Selected Foreground Layer -> Asset Type "Image" & selected Path with the icon only logo image and transparent background. Then selected Trim to Yes and Resize if needed.

[image]

- Selected Background Layer -> Asset Type "Image" & selected path. (Alternative, you can even set "Color")

[image]

- Click Next and clicked "Finish".

[image]

- Now, I right clicked on res folder and selected "Reveal in Finder".

[image]

- I copied all the folders inside the res folder and placed it inside: `my-app/resources/android/adaptiveicon/`

[image]

4. Next, I just need to add the below codes to the config.xml. Make sure each of every file in the `adaptiveicon` folder is linked here correctly, else it will throw "not found" errors during build.

```
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_background.png" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
```

Thats it. Now the App will have adaptive icons.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.
Info: If you chose the Background Color only way, delete the `ic_launcher_background_png` entries from the config.xml. Also you need to add the following line to get the build to work `<resource-file src="resources/android/adaptiveicon/values/ic_launcher_background.xml" target="app/src/main/res/values/ic_launcher_background.xml" />`

Comment: Attention: `cordova-android` has more resource templates it provides as the Android Studio generates. For example when removing and adding the platform / or on initial platform add. You will get more `mipmap-*-v26` folders. What would cause some devices to use the Ionic icon, if you don't provide these, too (android studio 3.5 does not generate them!). You could just delete these directories and he will take the `any` resolution. List of templates: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/tree/master/bin/templates/project/res

Comment: Just delete here Source/platforms/android/app/src/main/res following directories: `mipmap-ldpi`, `mipmap-ldpi-v26`, `mipmap-mdpi-v26`, `mipmap-hdpi-v26`, `mipmap-xhdpi-v26`, `mipmap-xxhdpi-v26`, `mipmap-xxxhdpi-v26`

Comment: @StefanRein thanks a lot for these useful comments #lifesavior.

Comment: I appreciate it @StefanRein Glad if my answer helps.

Comment: Just combine both solutions: <icon density> from "cordova resources" with the manual <resource-file> stuff.

Comment: @StefanRein I did this and it appears to fix my problem with the -v26 folders.  Is the <icon density> not really used if I use the manual <resource-file> stuff?

Comment: @NathanPrather I didn't try that. I don't remember how this works now, but I recall that I was using the following to generate the images https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-res and this did not provide (override) out of the box the icons in these mipmap folders. This would have caused me to use a graphics program and creating (overriding) them manually which I did not want to. Also I don't see any <icon density> entries right now in my config.xml. Only for <splash density="x" src="y">. Maybe you can try what you have and leave another comment how and if that worked! Thanks

Comment: Thanks @StefanRein.  Yeah for reasons I don't understand, as long as I include the icons and the manual resource stuff in config.xml everything works.  So I'll just go with it :-)  I tried removing the <icon> tags and it started showing the backed in cordova icons, etc.

Comment: Superb answer! Helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Cordova doesn't set Adaptive Icons yet. But it's easy enough to do manually after you've run Cordova build.

Change android:icon in AndroidManifest.xml to:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
```

Create ic_launcher.xml in res/drawable with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

Then add your two vector files ic_launcher_background.xml and ic_launcher_foreground.xml in res/drawable. These can be created with this tool: http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

And away you go! I hope Cordova bakes this into their builds soon.

Comment: it works fine. AndroidManifest.xml can also be easily changed in a build shell script using the following command `sed -i '' 's#@mipmap/icon#@drawable/ic_launcher#' platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: More tests: It works only with Oreo devices, not with former platforms where default android icon is then used.

Answer (score 2):

So here's an update for Ionic v4 and Cordova Android: 6.4.0. Notable changes to `0x6368656174`'s answer were:

- Removing `app/src/main` from the resource targets.
- My background.xml was in a `values` folder (i did not have a foreground as i used a png)
- The `edit-config` Manifest file location is in the same directory `file="AndroidManifest.xml"`

I struggled for a few days but this is what works for me:

config.xml

```
<widget ... xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="resources/android/values/ic_launcher_background.xml" target="res/values/ic_launcher_background.xml" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" target="res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" target="res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
         <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
    </edit-config>
    </platform>    
</widget>
```

**PHEW**

Answer (score 2):

I may be late to the party, but I struggled to get this working because (a) using PhoneGap Build, and (b) doing things by hand, not using Android Studio. So, for those playing along at home, here's all **I** had to do to get adaptive icons working:

1. Inside `<platform name="android">` in my `config.xml`, I set:

```xml
        <resource-file src="www/pwa/android/icon-bg.png"               target="app/src/main/res/mipmap/ic_bg.png" />
        <resource-file src="www/pwa/android/icon-fg.png"               target="app/src/main/res/mipmap/ic_fg.png" />
        <resource-file src="www/pwa/ic/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="www/pwa/ic/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="www/pwa/android/ic_launcher.xml"           target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" />
        <resource-file src="www/pwa/android/ic_launcher_round.xml"     target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" />

        <!-- Per https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2576077 -->
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
        </edit-config>
```

2. The PNG files in the config above are self-explanatory. The XML file referenced as `ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml` are identical, I just created this file at the source location and copied it in via the resource tags above. This is the contents of both of those XML files, reference as the src `public/pwa/android/ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_bg"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_fg"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

**Note** I'm targeting phonegap ver 8.1.1 (`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.1.1" />`) The post at https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2576077 was helpful in illuminating the fact that you have to use different `target` paths on your `<resource-file` tags, depending on the `cli` version you are using.

Hope this helps, hit me with questions if I missed anything. Cheers!

Comment: THANKS! Finally, I was able to add the AI to my PGB project!!

Answer (score 0):

**Android**
icon-android-foreground.png
432*432 px 
72dpi

**ios**
png without transparent
72dpi

Android Reference
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

```js
  const CordovaRes = require('cordova-res');
  const iconFolder = {
    dev: 'test',
    test: 'test',
    beta: 'beta',
    betaInternal: 'beta',
    betaRelease: 'beta',
    production: 'production'
  }[ENV];
  const sourcePath = `resources/_environments/${iconFolder}/`;
  const options = {
    resourcesDirectory: 'resources',
    platforms: {
      ios: { icon: { sources: [`${sourcePath}/icon-ios.png`] } },
      android: {
        'adaptive-icon': {
          icon: { sources: [`${sourcePath}/icon-android.png`] },
          foreground: { sources: [`${sourcePath}/icon-android-foreground.png`] },
          background: {
            sources: [{ type: 'color', color: '#b5c429' }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
 CordovaRes(options);
```

Answer (score -4):

You will first need to update Cordova to 7.0. [Cordova 7.0](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html) gives support for Android Oreo. Once you have created an app using Cordova 7, then you will have to manually create the adaptive icons using the native Android code. This [Medium blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/implementing-adaptive-icons-1e4d1795470e) will help you with that. Once you have created your [Adaptive Icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html), you can add them to your `config.xml` like this -

```
<platform name="android">
    <!--
        ldpi    : 36x36 px
        mdpi    : 48x48 px
        hdpi    : 72x72 px
        xhdpi   : 96x96 px
        xxhdpi  : 144x144 px
        xxxhdpi : 192x192 px
    -->
    <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
</platform>
```

Comment: Adaptive icons use foreground and background .xml files, which can be generated via the Image Asset Studio. How are these files loaded into Cordova via config.xml?