# Cordova Adaptive Icon Linking File Resources Error

Tags: android, xml, cordova

I used android studio to generate my image assets and moved the files over to res/android and followed the changes to the config.xml outlined here : [Android Oreo - how do I set Adaptive Icons in Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523610/android-oreo-how-do-i-set-adaptive-icons-in-cordova)

Right off the bat I get an error: 
`Source path does not exist: res/android/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml`
as my image asset did not generate a drawable folder. If I comment out the lines:

```
<!-- <resource-file src="res/android/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml" target="app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml" /> -->
<!-- <resource-file src="res/android/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml" target="app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml" /> -->
```

the build is able to begin but I receive linking errors:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  /home/jaimeandres/git/firebones/FireBonesMobileApp/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml:4: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground (aka com.firebones.app:mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground) not found.

  /home/jaimeandres/git/firebones/FireBonesMobileApp/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml:4: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground (aka com.firebones.app:mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground) not found.

  error: failed linking file resources.
```

below are the resources generated by Android Studio

[image: Image of resources generated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to individually add foreground.png to each dpi

```
    <platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="res/android/values/ic_launcher_background.xml" target="app/src/main/res/values/ic_launcher_background.xml" />
        <!-- <resource-file src="res/android/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml" target="app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_foreground.xml" /> -->
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher_round.xml" />
        <!-- hdpi -->
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
        <!-- mdpi -->
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />

        <!-- xhdpi -->
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
        <!-- xxhdpi -->
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
        <!-- xxxhdpi -->
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_round.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/android/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" target="app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ic_launcher_foreground.png" />
    </platform>
```